# Identify an old apples to apples kind of card game

Tags: identify-this-game

There is a card game from when I was young, around 1980 (could be even older). The game is in Finland, quite possibly translated to finnish from it's original language. Might also be a finnish game originally.

There are 2 kinds of cards: questions and answers (just like apples to apples). There are something like 50 cards total, every question has a "correct" answer pair, so there are equal amount of questions and answers.

When paired, the two cards have a drawn character's upper body on one card and legs on the other card. The full character represents a profession like a chef, fisherman, baker and so on. Mismatched pairs are weird, like a fisherman's rubber boots combined with baker's hat. In the same fashion, question/answer pairs are quite ordinary when paired correctly, but funny or absurd when mismatched.

Examples:
"Do you cry often?"
"Do you brush your teeth with dirt?"
"Only when I see you."
"Just like you do."

I can't remember the rules or the gameplay, I only remember going thru different pairings to see how funny answers there could be for a question.